# std::min of std::chrono::duration of different types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, stl-algorithm

Consider following code:

```
// durations are from std::chrono
auto a = get_duration_1(); // milliseconds, will vary in future versions
auto b = get_duration_2(); // seconds, will vary in future versions
auto c = std::min(a, b);
```

It doesn't compile because compiler cannot instantiate correct version of `std::min` because of different argument types.

Of course, now it's possible to specify type explicitly using `std::min<milliseconds>`. In future versions of this code, types will vary. What is the generic way of doing that without knowing exact duration types?

Comment: If there's no specified and existing specialization of [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) for [`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) (and there isn't) then no there is no generic (and "nice") way. Except to make such a specialization yourself. And if you need it in more than a couple of places, then such a specialization might be a good idea.

Comment: [std::min](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) does not have any version that accepts different argument types. Either cast one of the arguments or both.

Comment: I changes question so that need for generic code is shown explicitly.

Comment: Note that converting to a lower resolution TimePoint truncates and so requires an explicit cast to accomplish your desired goal.

Comment: @doug Thanks for useful remark. The thing is that I want to avoid that. (E.g. casting `microseconds`, which may appear in future, to `milliseconds`.) That's why I was looking for _generic_ way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given two durations, `D1 d1` and `D2 d2` ...

You can convert both durations to their common type, `std::common_type_t<D1, D2>`, and then find the minimum of those values.

Or just call `std::min<std::common_type_t<D1, D2>>(d1, d2)` and let them be converted to that type as needed.

This works because `std::common_type` is specialized to do the right thing for `duration` types, see [time.traits.specializations] in the C++ standard.

Comment: That can be wrapped in a function template, can't it? Useful utility, for more than just `std::chrono`

Comment: Looks like a solution. In this specific case with `auto` variables, should I do `std::common_type<decltype(a), decltype(b)>`?

Comment: Yes, of course. In your case, `D1` is `decltype(a)` and `D2` is `decltype(b)`, so substitute accordingly. But be careful: that should be `common_type_t` not `common_type`

Comment: I mistyped, forgot `_t`. Correct version: `std::common_type_t<decltype(a), decltype(b)>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following function:

```
#include <chrono>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto generic_min(const T1& duration1, const T2& duration2)
{
    using CommonType = typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type;
    const auto d1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<CommonType>(duration1);
    const auto d2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<CommonType>(duration2);
    return std::min(d1,d2);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only mark one answer as correct. Thank you for exact code!