# std::chrono: Subtract durations with a min value

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have the following code:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
...
auto duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
      std::chrono::milliseconds(getDelayBeforeNextExecution()) - duration);
```

In other words that function returns time before the next execution, but it should take into account how long it took (so if the next execution is in 20s, but I have spent 6s, it will be only 14s).

How do I do subtraction of durations but keep a minimum (non-negative)? Do I need to explicitly compare with chrono::zero and return chrono::zero?

Comment: What type does `getDelayBeforeNextExecution()` return?  `std::chrono` code can look rather elegant, while this code looks cluttered.

Comment: @DrewDormann The code is expected to return std::chrono::milliseconds. I don't have flexibility of changing this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) with a lower boundary of std::chrono::milliseconds::zero().

**Edit**: [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) would be better fit, as Drew pointed out in the comments.

Comment: `std::max` would be the function to call if you only have a _lower_ boundary.

Comment: Thanks! So this will work with chrono object?

Comment: @gruszcy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789935/stdmin-of-stdchronoduration-of-different-types

Answer (score 1):

I recommend working with `time_point`s as opposed to `duration`s:

```
start += std::chrono::milliseconds(getDelayBeforeNextExecution());
```

And then use the `_until()` family of functions to wait if need be, e.g.:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_until(start);
```

`sleep_until` will return immediately if `start` is in the past.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I need to return the delay from the function, because the library consumes it and decides when to run next.

Comment: Ok, in that case @jannarc's answer looks better to me.